# ImportError when I tried to import pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am just a beginner in python. I installed ipython-notebook by using anaconda. I can't import pandas, matplotlib. I tried the way in the "Reason" but it didn't work. Could anyone help me? Thank you!

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

/Users/hongliwang1/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     11                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     12                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
---> 13                       "extensions first.".format(module))
     14 
     15 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: dlopen(/Users/hongliwang1/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hongliwang1/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
  Reason: image not found not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo pip install pandas` ?

Comment: Thank you! I tried just now but it says : The directory '/Users/hongliwang1/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: Are possibly logged onto someones computer with a different user account?

Comment: Looks like you start from pandas source directory. Please change to a different directory and try again.

Comment: I tried sudo pip install pandas again and it looks like I ready install pandas. @MikeMüller Could you tell me how to change to a different directory? I am  new to python and pandas in general. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can change a directory on the command line with `cd`.  For example `cd .. ` goes up one directory and `cd /Users/hongliwang1/name/of/path/to/go/to` changes to the given path.